# JSON in String need to parse and put in map as key and value

Tags: java, json

```
 {Help:  
   [{"HelpOnName": "Merge", 
     "IsHelped": "Y",
     "Comment": 
   [{"answers": "This is where the real answer test is",
     "OtherDetails": "red",
     "OtherHelpNeeded": "No"}]
   }]
 }
```

This is the JSON I need to parse and put it in map as KEY / Value.

Problem is `HELP` is not been identified as JSONObject. Can you suggest how to parse and put in MAP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: It is because all keys must be string but Help array is not. Can you control source of the JSON?

Comment: Where do you generate the json ?

Answer (score 0):

By JSON specification all keys must be strings:

```
object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ] end-object
member = string name-separator value
```

If you can control source of the JSON you need to put `Help` array inside the quotes:

```
{"Help":  
   [{"HelpOnName": "Merge", 
     "IsHelped": "Y",
     "Comment": 
   [{"answers": "This is where the real answer test is",
     "OtherDetails": "red",
     "OtherHelpNeeded": "No"}]
   }]
 }
```

If you can't control source - remove Help from your JSON:

```
   [{"HelpOnName": "Merge", 
     "IsHelped": "Y",
     "Comment": 
   [{"answers": "This is where the real answer test is",
     "OtherDetails": "red",
     "OtherHelpNeeded": "No"}]
   }]
```

And parse it with regular JSON parser.

Comment: My json will have HELP and this format of json cant be changed. By useing above json i am now only getting the HELP as a key and rest all is skipped.

Comment: and also how we can identify that the element coming is an JSONObject or JSONArray on run time? i dont want to hard code the values to retrieve the array or object

Comment: @ami If Help is not the single field you can patch that output to be compatible with JSON format. I'm not familiar with java but I strongly believe that you can do it with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. yes i can do that. so now i am trying with below json,

[{"HelpOnName": "Merge", 
     "IsHelped": "Y",
     "Comment": 
   [{"answers": "This is where the real answer test is",
     "OtherDetails": "red",
     "OtherHelpNeeded": "No"}]
   }]

in this comments is an array. so my question is is it possible to identify the key as it is JSONObject and JSONArray at runtime and fetch their values in a generic approach. as i dont want to hard code values to fetch the values like

```
object.getString("answers");
object.getString("OtherDetails");
object.getString("OtherHelpNeeded");
```

so now in this case if i change my json then i need to change my code. as i am keeping this json in a property file and getting it at runtime to parse it.